# Undo `lazyload()` with the relationship default

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a `Query` object which was initially configured to `lazyload()` all relations on a model:

```
query = session.query(Article).options(lazyload('author'))
```

Is it possible to revert the relationship loading back to default? E.g. the relationship was configured with `lazy='joined'`, and I want the query to have `joinedload()` behavior without using `joinedload()` explicitly.

I was expecting [`defaultload()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.defaultload) to have this behavior, but in fact it does not: it references the *query default* instead of the *relationship default*. So I'm searching for kinda `resetload()` solution.

---

The reason for doing this is because I'm creating a JSON-based query syntax, and no relations should be loaded unless the user explicitly names them.

Currently, I'm using [`lazyload()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.lazyload) on all relations that were not explicitly requested, but want to go the other way around:  `lazyload()` all relations first, and then override it for some of them.

This would have made the code more straigntforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear:

> By default, all inter-object relationships are lazy loading.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading.html

So we are talking about a case in which a relation has been specifically marked as eager loading, then the queries are configured as lazy loading, then you want to "override the override" as it were.

Chaining calls to `options` will override earlier calls. I did test this a bit.

```python
q = s.query(User)  # lazy loads 'addresses'
q = s.query(User).options(contains_eager('addresses'))  # eager loads
q = s.query(User).options(contains_eager('addresses'))\
        .options(lazyload('addresses'))  # lazy loads
q = s.query(User).options(contains_eager('addresses'))\
        .options(lazyload('addresses'))\
        .options(contains_eager('addresses'))  # eager loads
```

However, it sounds like you're talking about just reverting the `lazyload` option, whereas the above case involves an explicit change to eager loading.

The `defaultload` docstring says its use case is to be chained to other loader options, so I don't think it's related.

Based on a glance through the source, I don't think this behavior is supported. When you update the loading strategy option, it updates a dictionary with the new loading strategy and I don't think there's still a reference to the old strategy, at least as far as I can tell.

You could keep a reference to the query object before `.options(lazyload(...))`, or just have an option to generate the query with or without the lazyload on everything.

Comment: Yes, looks like the only way is to do it manually, e.g. fetch the default `lazy` settings from the columns inspection. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To force everything to lazyload, ignoring what was specified on the relationship, you can use the `'*'` target.  From [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading.html#default-loading-strategies):

> affecting all relationships not otherwise specified in the query. This
>   feature is available by passing the string `'*'` as the argument to any
>   of these options:
>
> ```
> session.query(Article).options(lazyload('*'))
> ```

Then you can specify whatever load types you want per relationship or relationship chain.

```
# not sure how you are mapping json data to relationships
# once you know the relationships, you can build a list of them to load
my_loads = [joinedload(rel) for rel in json_rel_data]
query = session.query(Article).options(lazyload('*'), *my_loads)
# query lazy loads **everything** except the explicitly set joined loads
```

If you are joining on the relationships for query purposes, you can use `contains_eager` instead of `joinedload` in the options to use the already joined relationship.

```
my_eagers = [contains_eager(rel) for rel in json_rel_joins]
my_loads = [joinedload(rel) for rel in json_rel_loads]
query = session.query(Article
).join(*json_rel_joins
).options(lazyload('*'), *my_eagers, *my_loads)
```